# Facebook Send API 400 Bad Request

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-send-api

I'm trying to send a message from my app to a user using the Send API. I have the user_id from reading the userId when a message was sent to the page.

However, when I try to send a message using the Send API I get the error:

```
Failed calling Send API 400 Bad Request { message: '(#100) No matching user 
found',
type: 'OAuthException',
code: 100,
error_subcode: 2018001,
fbtrace_id: 'GmBQFOIlkFS' }
```

I saw on [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/578746852290927/?comment_id=255455878151560) that a lot of these errors might be because *"the page scoped ID does not belong to the app used for this request."*

The problem is that I'm not quite sure what that means.

I thought it might be because my webhook is on my website, but I was trying to send from localhost:3000. But then whether I tried sending it from my local server or from the server online, I get the same error code.

Comment: It means you need to have received this user id from the webhook via the same app in the first place.

Comment: OK maybe I'm a bit confused. I received the user id from both a messenger opt-in plugin, and from messaging the page. The user id was the same for both. I thought the user id was page scoped, not app scoped? I don't know where I've specified whether to use the development test app or the real thing.